When does a sum of an odd and even function gives us either an odd or an even function?
Greetings,
I'm currently trying to find a way to prove that this functional equation has no solution:
$$f(x+yf(x))+f(xf(y)−y)=f(x)−f(y)+2xy^2$$
I know that an eventual solution has to be odd: to do so, let's first replace $x$ and $y$ by $0$.
$$f(0+0*f(0))+f(0*f(0)-0)=f(0)-f(0)+2*0*0^2 \Leftrightarrow f(0) = 0$$
Then replace $x$ by $0$:
$$f(0+yf(0)) + f(0*f(y)-y) = f(0) - f(y) + 0*2y^2 \Leftrightarrow f(y) = -f(-y)$$
Now replace $x$ by $1$:
$$f(1+yf(1))+f(f(y)-y)=f(1)-f(y)+2y^2$$
Thus the left hand side is odd because it is a sum of odd functions, whereas the right hand side is a sum of two odd functions ($f(1)$ and $-f(y)$) and one even ($2y^2$).
My goal is to prove that the right hand side is not odd. But in order to do so, I must know when a sum of this kind can be odd.
Thank you for your answers,
Best regards.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Thank you very much for your answer. I'll edit the post right now.

Have you tried writing down what the definitions of odd and even functions tell you about such a sum?

I know that usually, a sum of even and odd functions is neither odd nor even. But I have no clue about the cases where this sum is odd or even.

Here the issue is that $f$ is not known, thus I can't graphically determine if $f$ is really even or odd. I have proven (see the edit) that an eventual solution must be odd, and I'm pretty sure this equation has none.

Supposed $f$ is an odd function, and $f=g+h$, where $g$ is odd and $h$ is even. Then $h=g-f$. But $g-f$ is a sum of two odd functions, and is therefore odd. Which means that $h$ is both odd and even. Therefore...?

Thank you very much for your answer. My doubt came from the French Wikipedia page about even and odd functions, where they said: "En général, la somme d'une fonction paire et une fonction impaire n'est ni paire ni impaire.", which translates to: "Generally, the sum of an even function and an odd function is neither even nor odd."

Yes! This is true unless one of the functions is identically zero.
